# repeater-type control for asp.net mvc 3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, repeater

is there any sort of control for .net mvc 3 (some html helper method perhaps) that works like an asp:repeater?

I've done some googling and only found some home grown solutions.

Here's what I need:
My users will have a drop down list of numbers, depending what they select (1-8), I need to repeat a set of code below to offer them the same list of input fields (between 1 and 8 times).

what would be the best way to accomplish this with mvc 3 and jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [jquery templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/) for this

I copy-pasted some code from a project I'm currently working on, but I think you get the picture how you can solve your problem with jquery templates.

You can put the templates in a partialview. For example:

```
<input type="hidden" id="productId" value="${ProductId}"/>
<div class="formElement">
    <label>@Globalization.Workorders.Domainname</label>
    <input type="text" id="domainname" name="domainname" />        
</div>
<div class="formElement">
    <label>@Globalization.Workorders.StartDate</label>
    <input type="text" id="startDate" value=""/>
</div>
<input type="submit" id="addHostingProduct" value="@Globalization.Workorders.Add"/>
<input type="button" id="addHostingProductCancel" value="@Globalization.Workorders.Cancel"/>
```

The template takes a json object or an array of json objects to render. The ${...} are replaced with values from the json.

I usually put the partialviews/templates in the view like this:

```
<script id="AddHostingProductTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    @Html.Partial("Templates/AddHostingProduct")
</script>
```

When you're page first loads, you can do something like this, to set the initial values:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        @foreach (var workOrderLine in Model.WorkOrderLines)
        {
            <text>
                  $('#AddHostingProductTemplate').tmpl(@workOrderLine.ToJson()).appendTo("#products")                
            </text>
        }

     });
</script>
```

The ToJson method is a method I put on the viewmodel, it just serializes the viewmodel into a json string.

When a user clicks a button or changes the dropdown, it's easy to use the template in your client side code to render the extra templates. Just use:

```
$('#AddHostingProductTemplate').tmpl({ someValue: '1', someOtherValue : ' test' }).appendTo("#products")
```

Hope this helps

Comment: ok I'm planning to use ajax to return a partial view and I want that view repeated x number of times depending on what's selected in the dropdown list.  I will also need to inject some text into the partialview for each iteration of the "loop"  Ex: Enter the FOURTH person's name....can that be done with these templates?

Comment: thanks much for the update...this looks promising.  I'm a little stuck on the the actual partial view though (in your case "AddHostingProduct")  How can I inject data from each iteration of my loop?  I see in your last line: $('#AddHostingProductTemplate').tmpl({ somevalue: ..... where it gets sent, but I'm not sure what the markup should look like on my actual partial view....

Comment: I added the partialview/template to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Put all 8 input fields on the page, and use jQuery to show/hide the fields based on the selected number in the select box.

Comment: no, there will be a lot of data for each of the iterations and I really don't want to pass all of that down to the client.

Comment: I guess I don't understand unless I see more code ... but wrap each section of data in a Div and show and hide each div.  Only 8 iterations.

Comment: no I think you do understand, it's just not as "elegant" a solution as I'm looking for.  I'm going to fetch the additional fields from the server with an ajax call and i want those fields to be repeated x number of times.  I could certainly pass them all down initially with the page load and show/hide as you suggest, but as I said in my last comment, there will be a LOT of information and I don't want to pass that down unnecessarily to the client.

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  Your problem is when the select box changes.  If I choose 5, it brings back all 5 ... but then what happens when I choose 3?  Does it go back to the server to get 3?  My way may have slow load time (which can be cached), but it is very fast on the client.

Comment: indeed, it would be instant on the client (I've used your approach a lot :P).  Going from 5 to 3 won't be a problem because I'm going to clear the entry point each time ( $("#myentrypoint").html("")  ).  I'm just trying to make this more elegant.  I'd like to just grab one "instance" of the partial view then repeat it x number of times for the value in the dropdown list.  I could do this with a for loop in code, but I still have the problem of injecting text into the partial view (see my comment to Robin)